# How can i add custom attribute to sales_order_view.xml under the SKU

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, template-override

I have already created `app/code/XXX/XXX/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` file.
I want to add created custom attribute for GTIN/EAN under the SKU attribute in items ordered list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**For your requirement, you have to do some work before completed:**

- Copy custom attribute value from product to order item
- Create new database column to quote_item and sales_order_item
- Copy custom attribute value from product to quote_item when customer have added product to cart.
- Copy custom attribute value from quote_item to order_item when customer submitted order.
- Update the template vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml which allow you render order item information to the order item line.

How to update the name.phtml

- Create a layout which named sales_order_view.xml
- Reference the block column_name
- Update the block template by using code block below

```
<referenceBlock name="column_name">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">yourvendor_module:templatename.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

**Option 2: Adding an additional_options**

**Add additional_options to quote item.** check the event at

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php:627
```

Comment: Custom attribute GTIN/EAN already assigned to the product like SKU.

Comment: You have to assign that attribute to order item like SKU. Their is 2 ways. I updated the answer.